# How to improve my unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

How do I build a new unit test case based on another case? Right now I am copy+paste'ing one test and extend it. This is a problem because if I want to make a change in the base test case, I have two cases to edit.

For example, below the first two function calls are identical:

```
def test_findHomography(self):
    print "Find Homography"
    kp1, kp2, matches = pano.findMatchesBetweenImages(self.images[0], self.images[1], 20)
    h = pano.findHomography(kp1, kp2, matches)
    print "Homography: "
    print h

def test_getBoundingCorners(self):
    print "Get Bounding Corners"
    kp1, kp2, matches = pano.findMatchesBetweenImages(self.images[0], self.images[1], 20)
    h = pano.findHomography(kp1, kp2, matches)
    corners1 = pano.getImageCorners(self.images[0])
    corners2 = pano.getImageCorners(self.images[1])

    min, max = pano.getBoundingCorners(corners1, corners2, h)

    print "Bounding Corners Left-Top: " + str(min)
    print "Bounding Corners Right-Bottom: " + str(max)
```

Comment: would a function be enough? you can have functions in the unit test file as long as they dont start with test_ they will behave as normal functions

Answer (score 0):

That specific case looks like common setup to me. Group the related tests below the same `TestCase` and extract the common initiating code into `setUp` for that `TestCase`. Unrelated tests go into different `TestCases`.

Otherwise I think Rui strategy would be appropriate.